# Using old database after magento install

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

My site was messed up by a novice developer and I had no option then to delete the old files, and install a fresh copy of magento 1.7.0.2 . My old Magento version was 1.6.

I want to use the old database as I got all of my product listing on it and everything is on that database. I find no way of getting those table (and in fact they are so many in number that its almost impossible to remember their names) in to my new installation..

I tried point my magento installation to old database by editing local.xml but was un-successfull as magento was throwing errors again and again..error was

```
table already exists and some description
```

and to me, these errors make sense

can somebody guide me how I can point my old database to magento without errors or how I can load my old data in to new magento installation..

I fear that simply importing sql database might not work

thanks

Comment: also, I am not sure about the health of database, as, to me it looks corrupted and incomplete, although not sure about it..the developer tried so many things before giving up and I am totally unsure about the thins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try to use a copy of the old database and install a new magento store over the existing database. That's what I've done so far and I could continue using the existing products. Be sure, that the database isn't corrupt.

Download the latest version of magento and start the setup routine. When Magento asks for the access data of your database, use the acess data of the "old" database. Magento will automatically upgrade your Database to Magento 1.7.

After that you have to install your theme and all the extensions you used in the old shop. Be sure, they are working on magento 1.7. And you have to copy the media folder, to use all images of products and categories.

This may help you:
http://indieswebs.com/blog/upgrade-to-latest-magento-using-fresh-install-technique/
http://neoshops.de/2013/08/03/how-to-upgrade-magento-using-old-database/

Comment: thanks for this comprehensive guide, I have a new version installed with new database, is there some way around so that I can change my database to the old database correctly?

Comment: I tried importing old database in current database of magento, and errors poped so badly

Comment: No, in my opinion there is no safe way, to use an "old" database in a newer store without insall or upgrade routine.

Answer (score 3):

I would try importing the old database first. It will get everything as long as it completes successfully. This page has detailed instructions: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

If the db import fails, Magento often makes changes (even if minor) the structure of its database between versions. Your best bet is to install the exact same version of Magento (1.6.something) then, point it to your old database by editing app/etc/local.xml. You should clear your cache so Magento loads the new version of the local.xml - Admin->system->cache manager->allcache->refresh

Then you can update to the latest version.